# Apache.NMS.AMQP setting prefetch size

Tags: amqp, nms, amazon-mq

I am using Apache.NMS.AMQP (v1.8.0) to connect to AWS managed ActiveMQ (v5.15.9) broker but am having problems with setting prefetch size for connection/consumer/destination (couldn't set custom value on either of them).

While digging through [source code](https://github.com/apache/activemq-nms-amqp/blob/1.8.0/src/NMS.AMQP/Meta/ConsumerInfo.cs) I've found that default prefetch value (DEFAULT_CREDITS) is set to 200.

To test this behavior I've written test that enqueues 220 messages on a single queue, creates two consumers and then consumes messages. The result was, as expected, that first consumer dequeued 200 messages and second dequeued 20 messages.

After that I was looking for a way to set prefetch size on my consumer without any success since `LinkCredit` property of `ConsumerInfo` class is readonly.

Since my usecase requires me to set one prefetch size for connection that is what I've tried next according to this [documentation page](http://activemq.apache.org/what-is-the-prefetch-limit-for), but no success. This are URLs that I've tried:

```
amqps://*my-broker-url*.amazonaws.com:5671?transport.prefetch=50

amqps://*my-broker-url*.amazonaws.com:5671?jms.prefetchPolicy.all=50

amqps://*my-broker-url*.amazonaws.com:5671?jms.prefetchPolicy.queuePrefetch=50
```

After trying everything stated above I've tried setting prefetch for my queue destinations by appending
`?consumer.prefetchSize=50` to queue name. Resulting in something like this:

`queue://TestQueue?consumer.prefetchSize=50`

All of above attempts resulted with effective prefetch size of 200 (determined through test described above).

Is there any way to set custom prefetch size per connection when connecting to broker using AMQP? Is there any other way to configure broker than through query parameters stated on this [documentation page](http://activemq.apache.org/components/nms/providers/amqp/uri-configuration)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From a quick read of the code there isn't any means of setting the consumer link credit in the NMS.AMQP client implementation at this time.  This seems to be something that would need to be added as it currently seems to just use a default value to supply to the AmqpNetLite receiver link for auto refill.

Their issue reporter is [here](https://issues.apache.org/jira/projects/AMQNET).